# How can I create an outlet in a different view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, controller

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7grjO.jpg

I want to create an outlet for project. The UIButton is in a different view controller. I can create outlets and actions, in the first view controller, but not any that I attached

Comment: Why do you need to create IBOutlet and IBAction in different viewController? You can prepare data by using variable and pass them into IBOutlet when the viewController appears.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code I could be very far off - please, if so, include code and it would help us.

My assumption is this - you have a UIButton in one UIView (with associated UIViewController) and wish to have code in another UIView (with a different UIViewController) know the button was clicked. also, your controllers are exposed publicly and are called "vc1" and "vc2".

You can accomplish this the following way:

**VC #1**

- The UIButton is called myButton. While you don't need to define this in IB (with associated IBOutlet and IBAction), we'll assume you have - just remember, you can do this completely in code.

**VC #2**

- You wish to trigger a function called myFunction(sender: UIButton), with all associated benefits, including knowing the properties of the button that was clicked.

Here's what you do:

**VC #1**

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton:UIButton!
@IBAction func tapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.sendAction(#selector(vc2.buttonClicked:)), to: nil, for: nil)
}
```

**VC #2**

```
public func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    // your code here
}
```

Another alternative is using the UIButton.sendAction() method.